# NLog: How to use different layout for different levels?

Tags: nlog

I saw this old question:
[How to apply different layouts to the same target in NLog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171663/how-to-apply-different-layouts-to-the-same-target-in-nlog)

The answer was: to use different targets for different levels. I'm not sure this will always work correctly.

A lot of time has passed since. Maybe now there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom layout, which has conditions. It will look like the [CompoundLayout](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/CompoundLayout)

e.g.

```xml
<layout type='ConditionalLayout'>
    <if condition="">
        <layout type='JsonLayout'> ...</layout>
    </if>
    <if condition="">
        <layout type='JsonLayout'> ...</layout>
    </if>

</layout>
```

The code file for `CompoundLayout` is here: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/dev/src/NLog/Layouts/CompoundLayout.cs

Answer (score 0):

It looks like no another ways to use different layout with one target.

And probably better just to use custom layout.